# show/hide a div with server-side logging

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

I have a website where people can answer simple questions.  After they submit their answers, they see a page with *correct* or *incorrect* for each question, and a long explanation of how to solve the question.

I want to get some analytics on how people use the explanations.

1. It could be that they read the explanations for every question.
2. They might read the explanations for only the questions that they didn't answer correctly.
3. They might read the explanations for only the questions that they answered correctly (unlikely I think).
4. They don't usually read the explanations, and are mainly interested in how many questions they got correct.

To this end, I want to add a "show explanation" link below each question after they submit the quiz.  The explanation will be hidden by default, and will be displayed when the user clicks the "show explanation" link.  This part is easy to do in CSS3 or jquery.  But I am not sure how to log the user click on the button for later analysis.

I want to avoid taking them to a different page for each question's explanation.  Is there a way to implement what I am thinking?

Comment: You may be interested in something called a tracking pixel.

Comment: @asafreedman thanks for the comment.  Looking at https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt *Track web traffic in the background* section thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since you're already using jquery. Make an ajax request for every user click on the "show explanation" button. This way you'd avoid taking them to a different page for each questions' explanation.

Example:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){

//        user clicks the 'show explanation' button
        $('#show_explanation_button').click(function(){

//          display explanation
          $('#show_explanation_div').css('display', 'block');

//          log user click
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'www.someurl.com/log_click/',
            data: {user_id : $('#user_id').val()}
          });
        });
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  It does the job!